# React-native-maps MapView.Circle

Tags: react-native, geometry, zooming, react-native-maps

I'm trying to get same size of my circle while zooming. I was tryging to do that with settings "scale" but it also doesnt work. How can i do that?
Could someone show me how can do that, maybe with any example ?

```
               <MapView.Circle
                    key = { (this.state.longitude + this.state.latitude).toString() }
                    center = {{latitude: this.state.latitude,
                        longitude: this.state.longitude} }
                    radius = { 100 }
                    strokeWidth = { 1 }
                    strokeColor = { '#1a66ff' }
                    fillColor = { '#1a66ff' }


                />
```

Best regards

Comment: A friendly reminder: This will likely get downvote(s), because it doesn't show that you've made any effort. You should probably post some code

Comment: You should include what you've tried so far. Right now, your question just falls under the asking for a tutorial flag. If you don't what you tried, people can't provide an explanation of where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to save the current map region to the state, this expresses the coordinate domain which the viewer sees...

```
onRegionChange(region) {
    // Update state
    this.setState({ mapRegion: region });
  }
  <MapView 
     onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
  />
```

With this, you can use simple trigonometry to resize the radius kind of like this...

```
size = {radius / Math.sqrt(this.state.mapRegion.longitudeDelta*this.state.mapRegion.longitudeDelta + this.state.mapRegion.latitudeDelta*this.state.mapRegion.latitudeDelta)}
```